# Enforcing coding standards for new code only

Tags: coding-style, standards

My company's code base is already big. But we are trying to enforce better quality with code hereon.

I am looking for a  way to enforce code standards for newly changed code while passing the existing code base.

Currently I have Jenkins as the CI tool, sonarqube as the coordinator into which resharper and stylcop can be plugged in.

but sonarqube is currently producing only a report.

From now on wards, the build has to be failed if it violates a standard or is unstable. Can it be done only at the CI tool level? what are the ways to enforce standards?

Are there alternative or better approaches for my scenario?

Comment: Are CI tools like Jenkins and Hudson the only ways to stop builds in case of violations? can sonarqube or any of the static code analysis tools can trigger the same?

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario is exactly what [Teamscale](http://teamscale.com) is built for: Accept the legacy problems and concentrate on the problems in new or modified code. Since Teamscale runs as a server and does an incremental analysis, you don't have to wait for the results or trigger any analysis. It also allows you to configure metric thresholds and quality goals that can be used to decide if a build should break or not. It also has a well-documented REST-API, so it can be easily connected to Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks ! Looks very promising indeed...will check it out and make a decision.....

Comment: Since it is a server tool, licenses for devops- build guys alone is enough right? it is much costlier for 10 developers.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use

https://github.com/exussum12/coverageChecker

For an offline check. This is written in PHP (so will need PHP on your CI server) but supports many standards for other reports.

This takes the full report, and the diff and only shows the errors on the lines which have changed.

So if you change a non conforming line, you will need to fix the reason it doesn't conform to standards before committing.

All new code has to conform to what ever standard you have set this way